# Calculate value in last months records

Tags: mysql

I have a table with customers and there power usage that's gets updated every night. I want to calculate the power usage per month.

```
SELECT customer, max(power_usage)-min(power_usage) AS lastmonthpower_usage FROM usage 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GOUP by customer
```

It seems like the calculation is done first on al the records per costumer in the database and then the where clause filters. 
I want to filter first on the date and then calculate the power usage.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Which one is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a subquery

```
SELECT customer, max(power_usage)-min(power_usage) AS lastmonthpower_usage 
from
(select * from usage 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)A
GOUP by customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine (without typo on `GROUP BY` and escaping the keywords / reserved words of MySQL) and should give [the expected result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6491395073f8cf5b1999bd47f4ffbac8).

But you can use the month and year on the `GROUP BY` too. Now you should get the correct minimum and maxmium value of the year and month for calculation without `WHERE`. Instead you can add `HAVING` to filter the grouped result to the last month (or any other month):

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS dYear, MONTH(`date`) AS dMonth, customer, MAX(power_usage) - MIN(power_usage) AS lastmonthpower_usage 
FROM `usage` 
GROUP BY customer, YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`)
HAVING dYear = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND dMonth = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=693a067f05425c69c9821d818d3650dc)

Also make sure to avoid / dont't use [keywords or reserved words of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) like `date` or `usage`. If you want to use keywords or reserved words in your query anyway you have to escape them with backticks (`` ` `` - `` SELECT * FROM `usage` ``).